# Reverse in Module.Map

Tags: module, ocaml, reverse

I take a look in the `Module.Map`, I wonder if there is any function define a reverse map.

```
val rev : 'a t -> 'a t
```

I tried to build a

```
val fold_left_map:(key -> 'a -> 'b -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'b map -> 'a

let rec fold_left_map f value map =
    match map with
    | Empty_map -> value
    | Node_map (left, key, data, right, _) ->
       fold_left_map f (f key (fold_left_map f value right) data) left
```

I get stuck when I try to use this function to build `rev`.

```
let rev map = fold_left_map (function key a x -> ...)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure where have you found a `Module.Map`, maybe it is part of your homework? So, I will presume, that you're talking about OCaml standard module `Map`.

### General information

Maps in OCaml are implemented using balanced binary trees. Trees, by itself do not have order, because their structure are not linear by definition. Although, they can be traversed in a specified order. But the ordering can be specified based on key comparison function. This can't be some arbitrary ordering.

### Your examples

Given the above, you should already know, that it is impossible to reverse a tree. You can only traverse it in a reverse direction. That means, that if you want to visit all nodes in an ascending order you need go to visit left one first, if you want to traverse in a descending order, your iteration function should visit the right node first.